# Getter returning incorrect value

Tags: java, arraylist, switch-statement, return-value, getter

I'm building an application for storing/searching/sorting cars and I'm running into an issue with one method.
I have six ArrayLists, storing variables of different data types:

```
Car c1 = new Car(1, "Ford", "Mustang", "2013", 200500, "1.3L", 'A', 5550.50); 
Car c2 = new Car(2, "Audi", "TT", "2012", 88000, "1.8L", 'C', 8450.00);
```

(and so on)

The seventh parameter along (char 'A'/'C') represents the car's grade. In another method, I want to print a String that describes the car's condition based on it's grade (e.g. 'A' = 'Like new', etc.). I've tried using a switch statement and an if/else statement for this, but regardless, the getter is returning the wrong grade - always 'B'.

Here is the method code (switch statement):

```
public String condition() {
    String condition = null;

    for (Car car: carList) {
    
        switch(car.getGrade()) {
        case 'A': case 'a': condition = "Like new"; break;
        case 'B': case 'b': condition = "Good condition, no damage"; break;
        case 'C': case 'c': condition = "Average condition, minor damage"; break;
        case 'D': case 'd': condition = "Poor condition, but functional"; break;
        default: condition = "Invalid"; break;
        }       
        }
    return condition;
}
```

getGrade() is a simple getter method, as such:

```
public char getGrade() {
    return grade;
}
```

Whenever I print the condition() method, it's assigning the grade 'B' to all the car objects and returning "Good condition, no damage".

The expected output is the string that corresponds to the car's grade.

I'm not sure why this is happening; as an aside, I have used the same approach before with accurate results. As an example, here is a section of code where a few of the car's details are being printed out, using getters:

```
System.out.println("Enter car ID: ");
        int id = sc.nextInt();
        for (Car car: carList) {
            if (car.getID() == id) {
                System.out.println("ID: " + car.getID() + "\nManufacturer: " + car.getManufacturer() + "\nModel: " + car.getModel() + "\nYear: " + car.getYear() + "\nPrice: " + car.getPrice() + "\n");
                return car;
            }
```

Here's the `Car` class code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;


public class Car {

    private String manufacturer;
    private String model;
    private String year;
    private int mileage;
    private String engineSize;
    private char grade;
    private double price;
    private String invalid;
    private int id;
    private static final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);


public Car() {
     manufacturer = inputManufacturer();
     model = inputModel();
     year = inputYear();
     mileage = inputMileage();
     engineSize = inputES();
     grade = inputGrade();  
     price = inputPrice();
     id = assignID();
     }

public Car(int id, String manufacturer, String model, String year, int mileage, String engineSize, char grade, double price) {
     this.id = id;
     this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
     this.model = model;
     this.year = year;   
     this.mileage = mileage;
     this.engineSize = engineSize;
     this.grade = grade;
     this.price = price;
     }


public int assignID() {
    id = count.incrementAndGet();
    return id;
}


public String inputManufacturer() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter manufacturer: ");
    manufacturer = scan.next();

    invalid = "[0-9~/!?#@*+%{}<>[]|_^].*$]";
    if(containsInvalid(manufacturer) == true) {
        System.out.println("Invalid characters in input. Please try again.");
        inputManufacturer();
    }

    return manufacturer;
}

public String inputModel() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter model: ");
    model = scan.next();

    invalid = "[0-9~/!?#@*+%{}<>[]|_^].*$]";
    if(containsInvalid(model) == true) {
        System.out.println("Invalid characters in input. Please try again.");
        inputModel();
    }
    return model;
}

public String inputYear() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter year: ");
    year = scan.next();

    invalid = "[a-zA-Z!?+=-£%^&*/.,#~@';:_-]";
    if(containsInvalid(year) == true ) {
        System.out.println("Invalid characters in input. Please try again.");
        inputYear();
    }
    else if (year.length() > 4) {
        System.out.println("Invalid year. Please try again.");
        inputYear();
    }
    return year;
}


public int inputMileage() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter mileage: ");
    mileage = scan.nextInt();

    return mileage;
}

public String inputES() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter engine size: ");
    engineSize = scan.next();

    invalid = "[~/!?#@*+%{}<>[]|_^]*$]";
    if(containsInvalid(engineSize) == true) {
        System.out.println("Invalid characters in input. Please try again.");
        inputES();
    }
    return engineSize;
}

public char inputGrade() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter grade: ");
    char g;
    g = scan.next().charAt(0);

    if (g == 'A' || g == 'B' || g == 'C' || g == 'D') {
        grade = g;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid grade. Please try again.");
        inputGrade();
    }
    return grade;
}


public double inputPrice() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter price: ");
    price = scan.nextDouble();

    return price;
}

public boolean containsInvalid(String toExamine) {
    if (toExamine.matches(invalid)){
    return true;
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Manufacturer: " + manufacturer + "\nModel: " + model + 
"\nYear: " + year + "\nMileage: " + mileage + "\nEngine size: " + engineSize + "\nGrade: " + grade + "\nPrice: " + price;

}
```

Getters and setters from this point onwards.

Comment: How is the field `grade` defined? I suspect it's something like `private static char grade`. If so, remove the `static`.

Comment: In any case, the pasted code isn't relevant to the question. Paste the definition of the `Car` class, and/or where you actually made `carList`. VTC: Not enough detail

Comment: And unrelated to your actual question: `grade` is pretty much a perfect match for using an `enum` value instead of a `char`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks for your comment! `grade` is defined as `private char grade` - no static keyword, sadly.

Comment: Actually: re-reading your `condition` method: It will check the grade from each car and only return the *last one*. There's no way this method returns any grade other than the one from the last car in the list.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I hadn't noticed that, much appreciated. I'll look into how to fix that.

Comment: And since you posted your `Car` class: two things about the `containsInvalid` method that immediately jump out at me: `invalid` should **really** be a parameter to that method and not a field that you set. Apart from breaking any multithreading, this approach also is ugly as sin. And second: you use `matches()` which would only return when *the whole string* matches the regex, but you use regex that only match a single character. You need `Matcher.find()` instead.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Fantastic, I'll implement those changes. I was also having issues with `matches()` but I didn't want to ask about all the concerns in one go. Thank you so much for all your help!